# SATA interface timeout and reset, on exact multiples of 30 minutes, under Linux. Kernel bug?

Tags: linux, kernel, hardware, bugs, sata

Frequently my system locks up for perhaps 60 seconds, with the hard drive light illuminated. This is followed by an apparent SATA reset. The system doesn't crash; filesystems are accessible as normal when the system unfreezes; there is never data loss, and handles never seem to become invalid. This behaviour is new, but I don't have a record of when it began. I never saw this happen under Ubuntu 16 or 18 (or Windows, but I no longer have a reasonable way to test that).

The system is old, but the hardware is stable. It is a Sony Vaio AR61M laptop. Currently:

Kernel: `5.4.0-65-generic x86_64`; Distro: `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS`

Each time this occurs, `dmesg` shows the following new entries (differing only in timestamp)

```
[529270.298716] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[529270.299231] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SATA.PRT0._SDD.SMS], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[529270.299254] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_SDD]
[529270.299258] Initialized Arguments for Method [_SDD]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
[529270.299260]   Arg0:   00000000088c3c01 <Obj>           Buffer(512) 40 00 FF 3F 37 C8 10 00
[529270.299282] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SATA.PRT0._SDD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
[529270.299327] ata3.00: unexpected _GTF length (8)
[529270.299897] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SATA.PRT0._SDD.SMS], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[529270.299908] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_SDD]
[529270.299910] Initialized Arguments for Method [_SDD]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
[529270.299911]   Arg0:   00000000088c3c01 <Obj>           Buffer(512) 40 00 FF 3F 37 C8 10 00
[529270.299922] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SATA.PRT0._SDD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
[529270.299957] ata3.00: unexpected _GTF length (8)
[529270.300000] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[529270.300649] ata3.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
```

Without exception, this always happens on an interval that is some **exact** multiple of 30 minutes. To me that suggests a watchdog timer is timing out, perhaps because an interrupt handler or a kernel module is buggy, but I'm not a Linux developer so that's supposition on my part.

Just to show how definite the time intervals are, since my last reboot the time offsets in seconds are below; the times in hours are exact, relative to 70 seconds after startup:

```
 10870  +3 hr
151270  +39 hr
178270  +7.5 hr
297070  +33 hr
356470  +16.5 hr
527470  +47.5 hr
529270  +0.5 hr
```

`lspci | grep SATA` yields

```
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
```

while `dmesg | grep AHCI` yields

```
[    1.586042] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0100 32 slots 3 ports 3 Gbps 0x7 impl SATA mode
```

In case it is relevant, /dev/sda is an Intel `SSDSA2M040G2GC`; /dev/sdb is a Hitachi `HTS547575A9E384`.

I haven't tried other drives, since I need to actually use the machine at the moment. But if anyone has any ideas, knows of any relevant bugs, or finds any of this familiar, please let me know.